# Excluding the first match with regex if it the match is too short in Python

Tags: python, regex

In Python, I am searching for strings between two words, namely `Introduction` and `Theory Development`:

```
string = "Introduction: What is game Game Theory ? Theory Development. Introduction: What is game Game Theory ? Probably real content is here. Theory Development."
```

In this particular case, I want to get the second one. In general, among all of the matches, I want to get the longest one. How could I do that?

Currently I do:

```
import re
regex = 'Introduction(.+?)Theory Development'
match = re.search(regex, string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
rawText = match.group(1)
```

Comment: You can't do that with regex alone. Use a regex to extract all matches (your pattern with `re.findall`). Then use `longest_match = max(matches)`.

Comment: But if you insist on doing it with regular expression, you want to use a *greedy* regex like in `'Introduction(.*)Theory Development`